# The section names of my latex document are not in the same font as the rest of the document, what do I do?

Tags: fonts, formatting, times

```
% Desenvolvido por: Prof. Dr. David Buzatto
%
% Baseado na documentação do abntex2 e nos modelos em
% Microsoft Word propostos pela Profa. Dra. Rosana F. L. Rodrigues
% e pela bibliotecária M.Sc. Maria Carolina Gonçalves do câmpus
% São João da Boa Vista do IFSP.
%
% Versão 1.51
% Data: 06/11/2018

\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,            % para impressão em verso e anverso.  Usar twoside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    %normalfigtabnum,
    %pnumromarab,
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,     % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
]{abntex2}



% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   PACOTES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% ---
% Pacotes básicos 
% ---
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}    % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
% ---
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf,abnt-emphasize=bf,bibjustif]{abntex2cite}  % Citações padrão ABNT


% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                          CONFIGURAÇÕES DOS PACOTES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
%
% Para desativar, tire o comentário de \begin{comment} e \end{comment} 
% das próximas linhas e comente a linha \usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
% acima.
% ---

%\begin{comment}
% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
    Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    \or
    Citado na página #2.%
    \else
    Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    \fi}%
% ---
%\end{comment}


% listagens
\definecolor{corComentario}{RGB}{150,150,150}
\definecolor{corString}{RGB}{206,123,0}
\definecolor{corPalavraChave}{RGB}{0,0,230}

\lstset{
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    lineskip=0pt,
    frame=tb,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    showstringspaces=false,
    stringstyle=\color{corString},
    commentstyle=\color{corComentario},
    keywordstyle=\color{corPalavraChave}
}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\ano}[1]{\def \oano {#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimirano}{\oano}

\newcommand{\mes}[1]{\def \omes {#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimirmes}{\omes}

\newcommand{\subtitulo}[1]{\def \osubtitulo {#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimirsubtitulo}{\osubtitulo}

\newcommand{\area}[1]{\def \aarea {#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimirarea}{\aarea}

\renewcommand{\coorientador}[1]{\def \ocoorientador {#1}}
\renewcommand{\imprimircoorientador}{\ocoorientador}

\newcommand{\grau}[1]{\def \ograu {#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimirgrau}{\ograu}

\newcommand{\curso}[1]{\def \ocurso {#1}}
\newcommand{\imprimircurso}{\ocurso}


% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---

\curso{Bacharelado em Engenharia Elétrica}
\grau{Bacharel em Engenharia Elétrica}

%exemplos
%\curso{Tecnologia em Sistemas para Internet}
%\grau{Tecnólogo em Sistemas para Internet}
%\curso{Especialização em Desenvolvimento de Aplicações para Dispositivos Móveis}
%\grau{Especialista em Desenvolvimento de Aplicações para Dispositivos Móveis}

\titulo{Investigações sobre os efeitos das bolhas e cintilações ionosféricas}

% caso não haja subtítulo, comente a linha abaixo
\subtitulo{Um estudo do posicionamento por satélite utilizando GPS na região brasileira}

\tipotrabalho{Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso}
\area{Posicionamento por Satélite}

\autor{Clodoaldo de Souza Faria Júnior}
\orientador{Prof.Dr. Bruno César Vani}

% caso não haja coorientador, comente a linha abaixo
\coorientador{Prof. Dr. Alison Oliveira Moraes}

\local{Presidente Epitácio}
\mes{Dezembro}
\ano{2021}

\instituicao{%
    Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia de São Paulo
    \par
    Câmpus Presidente Epitácio
}

\preambulo{\imprimirtipotrabalho\ apresentado ao Instituto Federal de Educação, Ciência e Tecnologia de São Paulo, como parte dos requisitos para a obtenção do grau de \imprimirgrau.
\\
\\
Área de Concentração: \imprimirarea}
% ---


% ---
% Configurações de aparência do PDF final
% ---

% alterando o aspecto da cor azul
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    %pagebackref=true,
    pdftitle={\@title}, 
    pdfauthor={\@author},
    pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
    pdfcreator={Nome Completo},
    pdfkeywords={Palavra chave 1}{Palavra chave 2}{Palavra chave 3}{Palavra chave n}, 
    colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,            % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,            % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,            % color of file links
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 


% ---
% Comandos do autor
% ---

% comando para inserir autor e ano
\newcommand{\citeauthorandyear}[1]{\citeauthoronline{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}


% ---
% Novo list of (listings) para Quadros
% ---

\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\listofquadrosname}{Lista de Quadros}

\newfloat[chapter]{quadro}{loq}{\quadroname}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listofquadrosname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}

% configurações para atender às regras da ABNT
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}
\counterwithout{quadro}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill--\hfill}

% Configuração de posicionamento padrão:
\setfloatlocations{quadro}{hbtp}



% --- 
% Espaçamentos entre linhas e parágrafos 
% --- 

% O tamanho do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% ---
% compila o indice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---







% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   INÍCIO DO DOCUMENTO
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    
% Seleciona o idioma do documento (conforme pacotes do babel)
%\selectlanguage{english}
\selectlanguage{brazil}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 


% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \pretextual

% ---
% Capa
% ---
%\imprimircapa
\input{pre01Capa}
% ---

% ---
% Folha de rosto
% (o * indica que haverá a ficha bibliográfica)
% ---
%\imprimirfolhaderosto*
\input{pre02FolhaDeRosto}
% ---

% ---
% Inserir a ficha catalográfica
% ---
\input{pre03FichaCatalografica}

% ---
% Inserir folha de aprovação
% ---
\input{pre04FolhaDeAprovacao}

% ---
% Dedicatória
% ---
\input{pre05Dedicatoria}

% ---
% Agradecimentos
% ---
\input{pre06Agradecimentos}

% ---
% Epígrafe
% ---
\input{pre07Epigrafe}

% ---
% Resumos
% ---
\input{pre08Resumo}
\input{pre09Abstract}

% ---
% inserir lista de ilustrações
% ---
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
% ---

% ---
% inserir lista de quadros
% ---
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listofquadrosname}{loq}
\listofquadros*
\cleardoublepage
% ---

% ---
% inserir lista de tabelas
% ---
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage
% ---

% ---
% inserir lista de abreviaturas e siglas
% ---
\input{pre10ListaSiglas}
% ---

% ---
% inserir lista de símbolos
% ---
\input{pre11ListaSimbolos}
% ---

% ---
% inserir o sumário
% ---
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage
% ---






% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  ELEMENTOS TEXTUAIS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\textual

\input{capitulo01Introducao}
\input{capitulo02RevisaoLiteratura}
\input{capitulo03Metodologia}
\input{capitulo04ResultadosDiscussao}
\input{capitulo05Conclusoes}
%\input{capitulo06Cronograma}






% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                 ELEMENTOS PÓS-TEXTUAIS
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\postextual


% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Referências bibliográficas
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\bibliography{referencias}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Glossário
% ----------------------------------------------------------
%
% Consulte o manual da classe abntex2 para orientações sobre o glossário.
%
%\glossary


% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Apêndices
% ----------------------------------------------------------
%\input{pos01Apendices}


% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Anexos
% ----------------------------------------------------------
%\input{pos02Anexos}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------
% ÍNDICE REMISSIVO
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

%\phantompart

%\printindex


\end{document}
```

Comment: If your headings are in sans-serif, and you do not want them to be, you might try `\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\familydefault}`. (Your class sets this to `\sffamily`.) You might also need to redefine `\setparaheadstyle`. Or, if you never need a sans-serif font, you could `\renewcommand{\sffamily}{lmr}`.

Comment: If you mean that the headings are in caps, you want to remove the `=TITLE` class options.

Comment: If you mean your titles are in boldface, they are supposed to be.